# haystack url to search in templates

Tags: django-templates, django-haystack

I think this might be a simple one,

I have installed haystack with whoosh backend. Followed the tutorial and all is working well.

Now I am trying to create a **link from other templates to the search url**. And I am not figuring out how to do it.

my search url is:

```
url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
```

and I want to refer to link to it from another template. something like:

```
<a href={% search url %}>
```

I am using Django 1.3.5 and Haystack 1.2.7

Help would be appreciated.
cheers

a

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so found out the solution for my own question.

In the url declaration, if I use the optional name i can the use it to refer to the search url.

In urls.py:

```
url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls'), name='haystack_search')
```

and in template:

```
<a ref={% url haystack_search %}>search page</a>
```

Comment: You don't need to do the first part, and I don't think it actually does anything (I'm not sure what, if anything, the name parameter is used for if you specify it in an include rule). Haystack provides the "haystack_search" url name itself, which is why your {% url haystack_search %} call works.

Comment: `<a href="{% url haystack_search %}">search page</a>`